# Polymorphism broken when changing web site project to web application project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, polymorphism

Greetings,

I just converted an ASP.NET Web Site Project to a [Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx) in VS 2010.  After I run the application though it seems that my class polymorphism broke.  I don't have a clue as to why this could occur.

So in the following code when I call base.OnLoad(e) I am getting errors in the base class because the variable myString is null.  In fact all the variables for the Base class are null.  I can do

> base.myString = this.myString;

before

> base.OnLoad(e);

but this doesn't seem to be polymorphic to me.

---

**Code:**

```
public partial class FormA : Web.ClassB 
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        myString = "TEST";

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}

public class ClassB 
{
    protected String myString;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Class C has a virtual OnLoad method (not shown here)
    }
}
```

Comment: How likely is it that "... my class polymorphism broke."? Wouldn't a bug/misunderstanding in your code seem more likely?

Comment: Perhaps it is a bug, but all I did really was change the web project type.  This code worked fine in the Web Site Project.  When I look at FormA.base all the variables are null, what could cause this to occur given that the code for these classes has not changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ClassB is in a namespace or a member of another class. Do you have your namespaces/scoping correct because I have ran into problems like that converting web sites to web apps.

Comment: Ahh, I think you might have nailed this one on the head. But I still feel well, stuck with a dillema.  In my solution I have 3 projects (3 seperate assemblies), and my Class B is in the Class Library (namespace = "Lib") and Class A is in the web project (default namespace = "Web").  Do I have to use the same namespace for both projects?  Can it be "Base.Lib" and "Base.Web"?